# Flutter : how to change the local value in other function?

Tags: function, flutter, widget, return-value

I don't know if this is possible but how to change a value in another function ?

for exemple in this function, the function receive the value but it can' return it because it return the widget "Switch":

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustumSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  bool _switchGD;
  CustumSwitch(this._switchGD);

  @override
  _CustumSwitchState createState() => _CustumSwitchState();
}

class _CustumSwitchState extends State<CustumSwitch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
        value: widget._switchGD,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            widget._switchGD = !widget._switchGD;
          });
          
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use *setState()* method in every case where you want to dynamically change values during build.

```
onChanged: (value) {

  setState((){                        
    widget._switchGD = !widget._switchGD;
  });
                        
});
```

It will work.. But I recommend you to learn something about Flutter **best practices**, because you never want to use non-final fields as Widget parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I just forget the setState, this is just a exemple!

Thanks, I didn't test it ‍♂️

Comment: do you have a link from where I can learn Flutter best practices ?

Comment: I test it but it doesn't work , the original variable in the caller function doesn't change!

Comment: @ismail [performance](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices), [naming conventions](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-best-practices-c3db1c3cd694). There are plenty of sources, you can find it on google but in your solution I see only problem with non-final fields. When you need this bool as parameter you wouldnt be able to change it directly, you can use local variable instead.

Comment: @ismail try to move bool _switchGD from CustumSwitch, to _CustumSwitchState and use it as local variable instead of parameter, but you have to set its initial value.

Comment: @ismail 
`class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}
class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch> {

  bool _switchGD = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
        value: _switchGD,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _switchGD = !_switchGD;
          });

        });
  }
}`

Comment: @ismail it's comment section so it don't look great but the point is that you remove switchGD from your CustomSwitch class and add it to your CustomSwitchState class with initial value of false - or true it is up to you.